# Is this crawl space wall load bearing?

Tags: framing, studs, carpentry

Before I start calling contractors, does this wall appear to be load bearing?

It's the exterior wall of a crawl space under the kitchen. I believe the kitchen to be an addition.

[image]

Comment: I would guess it is.  Exterior wall plus what looks like floor joists on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

From the one picture, all I can say is 'probably'.

Points toward it being load bearing:

1. Exterior wall. Those are almost always load bearing.
2. Appears to have a substantial header on top of it.
3. Looks like the header has floor joists on top of it.

Points against:

1. At least one of those studs does not appear to be touching the header.
2. With a header that thick, the header might be actually bearing all the load into whatever foundation is at the end of it.

**For the truly best answer, get a structural engineer in there before you plan any changes.** For the (distant) next-best, take about ten times as many pictures and a drawing and re-ask your question here.

Comment: Emphasized the critical part of the answer.